# Random value in array with Delphi

Tags: delphi

I have the following code.

```
const
   dimensions: array [1 .. 5] of string = ('100 ', '200', '300 ', '400', '500 ');
```

What I do is pick a random value in that array to display on ShowMessage ();

But how to do that, someone might say as you chose a random value from an array?

Comment: Use `RandomRange(1,5)` and use that as the index to the array.

Comment: I try : ShowMessage(dimensiones[RandomRange(1,5)]); but show this error "E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'RandomRange'"

Comment: Google "delphi randomrange" suggests [Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=RandomRange&ExpandCode1=Yes): "uses
  Math,   // Unit containing the RandomRange command"

Comment: @mrbatch Acrually that code is incorrect as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [RandomRange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.RandomRange) to pick a value between 1 and 5. Do so like this:

```
Index := RandomRange(1, 6);
```

It may seem a little counter-intuitive, but the lower limit is inclusive, and the upper limit is non-inclusive.

Another way would be to use Random directly:

```
Index := 1 + Random(5);
```

You could even do away with your array and write:

```
IntToStr(100*RandomRange(1, 6))
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is this

```
    myString := dimensions[Random(Length(dimensions))];
```

Remember to initialize the random seed before using Random, otherwise you will not be getting a "true" random value.

```
    Randomize;
    myString := dimensions[Random(Length(dimensions))];
    Showmessage(myString);
```

Comment: That code is wrong. Array bounds are 1..5. Your code uses indices 0..4. Once you fix it, your answer will Be a subset of mine.